# Change the YYYY-MM-DD HH-PM/AM date to same date with 24 hour format

Tags: excel

Got a question about how I can change a date/time format in Excel.

I have this format `2020-05-29 06-PM` and I need to change it to be like this `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM`

I have a table of above 20000 lines which is needed to be changed.

I already try to do like this - `=TEXT(A3,”YYYY:MM:DD HH”)’` and I receive an `#ERROR!`
Any suggestion on how can I do it?

Also important note that I'm using excel spreadsheets in Google Drive. If it's even possible to make in Google Drive Excel spreadsheets or should I use regular Excel on my PC?

**EDIT1**
I have a first column like this and I did accordingly to @Gary'sStudent answer and I it goes strange in one way.

```
2020-05-29 06-PM
2020-05-29 05-PM
2020-05-29 04-PM
2020-05-29 03-PM
2020-05-29 02-PM
2020-05-29 01-PM
2020-05-29 12-PM
2020-05-29 11-AM
2020-05-29 10-AM
2020-05-29 09-AM
2020-05-29 08-AM
2020-05-29 07-AM
2020-05-29 06-AM
2020-05-29 05-AM
2020-05-29 04-AM
2020-05-29 03-AM
2020-05-29 02-AM
2020-05-29 01-AM
2020-05-29 12-AM
2020-05-28 11-PM
2020-05-28 10-PM
2020-05-28 09-PM
2020-05-28 08-PM
```

Transforms to this

```
2020-05-29 06-00
2020-05-29 05-00
2020-05-29 16-00
2020-05-29 15-00
2020-05-29 14-00
2020-05-29 13-00
2020-05-30 00-00
2020-05-29 23-00
2020-05-29 22-00
2020-05-29 09-00
2020-05-29 08-00
2020-05-29 07-00
2020-05-29 06-00
2020-05-29 05-00
2020-05-29 04-00
2020-05-29 03-00
2020-05-29 02-00
2020-05-29 01-00
2020-05-29 12-00
2020-05-28 11-00
2020-05-28 10-00
2020-05-28 21-00
2020-05-28 20-00
```

Why it goes like 16:00/15:00 when it's supposed to go 04:00 and 03:00 accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With data in **A1**, in another cell enter:

```
=DATEVALUE(LEFT(A1,10))+TIME(MID(A1,12,2),0,0)+IF(RIGHT(A1,2)="PM",TIME(12,0,0),0)
```

and format as you require:

[image]

**NOTE:**

There are three parts:

- `DATEVALUE()` gets the date
- `TIME()` gets the hour
- `IF()` bumps by 12 hours if required

Format is 24 hr.

**EDIT#1:**

Here is the full posted data set with the output in column **C**:

[image]

Comment: Can you take a look on edited question. I implement your answer accordingly. But still receive some weird mistake now in formating

Comment: I add AM PM accordingly and the result as well.

Comment: @Hexycode  I can't duplicate your results....I copied the data from your question and posted my results in my **EDIT#1** ..................sadly, I don't know how to resolve this................

Comment: Was my bad I forget to change one A in your code. So it's working now for me. I'm confirming and upvoting your answer. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
=TEXT(A1,"YYYY-MM-DD [hh]-mm")
```

or same format in Custom Format [CTRL]+[1]